# Javascript get all files in a folder that are inside another fold

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I get all the js files that are inside of folder, and that folder is inside of another folder?

I'm very new to JS, and I know I can get it using `readdirSync` but I can only get all the files in the current directory.

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    console.log(file + "✅"); 
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
```

Here's my file structure.

[image]

Comment: have a google for `glob`.

Comment: Wow! I just did. Looks good! Why not post it as an answer? I mean with a sample code of course to make it a valid answer, not that I like spoonfeeding.

Comment: You could use a recursive method as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827612/node-js-fs-readdir-recursive-directory-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with [`glob`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob). It’s a package but allows for finding files at any level.

```
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
})
```

Comment: You helped me a lot by introducing the module `glob`. :) BUT, I spent around 51mins+ figuring out the pattern, plus I didn't realize so soon that my `const model...` makes the final path incorrect. For the record, here's my path, just in case in the future, some newbie js person like me finds this. ```const files = glob.sync(__dirname + "/*/*.js")```